# Dependencies vs devDependencies in monorepo

Tags: javascript, dependencies, monorepo, cl

[This cl tool](https://github.com/changesets/changesets/blob/main/packages/cli/README.md#getting-started) can be installed as a devDependency. But they say to install it as a dependency if you are in a monorepo.

Why is that?

Comment: check it out this line: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1079#issuecomment-337660289

Comment: @Martinez thank you very much! I don't know if I would ever found that comment as I am not using Lerna and would have probably ignored that issue. If you want, you can turn your comment into an answer. I'm sure it will be useful for other people.

Comment: The answers don't rely reply as to why changesets recommends installing it as a dependency and not as a devdependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`devDependencies` in the root package.json can be used in all packages in the monorepo. This is generally used to co-locate test-related deps and config (jest, eslint, etc).

A couple caveats:

1. This only works for non-CLI `devDependencies`. If you need to run a
   CLI from a child package, that CLI needs to be in that package's
   devDependencies. (transpiling, flowcopy, etc)
2. All `dependencies` for a
   given child package still need to be listed in that child's
   package.json. (obvious, perhaps? just clarifying)

Source: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1079#issuecomment-337660289

Comment: Just wanted to mention that it's not clear whether this is just something specific to Lerna or it's valid in general for any monorepo.